# How to print welcome message to console from Apache

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I downloaded microapache and noticed it has an empty console when starting (Windows Machine, running from usb stick)

I want to display the line "Welcome! go to localhost:8888 to view my app" to the console  dos box.

Is it possible to define an entry in httpd.conf for that, e.g. "welcome_message "hello" " ?

**update**: my "go.bat" closes within 5 secs so I want to display it in the apache console, my go.bat looks like this:

```
@echo off start /min "QueryTool" server/mapache.exe -w 
ping localhost -n 5 > nul 
@start "" /b "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://localhost:8888
```

so.. this one closes and I would like to display a message in the "apache window" in case the user for some reason can not open localhost:8888 automatically.

Comment: You mean when you run `go.bat` you want that message to be displayed to the Command Prompt?

Comment: no, my go.bat closes in 1 sec, i want to display it in the apache console window that stays there, hang on i will update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try, it may not be what you wanted but its the closest I could come up with:

go.bat

```
@echo off 
start launch.bat
ping localhost -n 5 > nul 
@start "" /b "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://localhost:8888
```

create a new file called launch.bat:

```
@echo off
echo Welcome! go to localhost:8888 to view my app
mapache.exe
```

That has output:

```
Welcome! go to localhost:8888 to view my app
Apache/1.3.37 (Win32) PHP/4.4.7 running...
```

If you only want the message to be displayed you could do:

```
@echo off 
start /min "QueryTool" server/mapache.exe -w 
ping localhost -n 5 > nul 
@start "" /b "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://localhost:8888
echo Welcome! go to localhost:8888 to view my app
@pause
```

In which cause the go.bat will stay open with the welcome message until they press any key to close it.